# Angular ng-options access iterable

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and have the following code:

```
<select ng-model="f.value" ng-options="item.value as item.label for item in f.options | filter: myProcessFilter" />
```

And I can filter the options easily with something like this

```
        $scope.myProcessFilter = function (v, i) {
            console.log(v);
            // do some filtering and return
        }
```

However, now i want to pass a variable to processFilter.  like so

```
<select ng-model="f.value" ng-options="item.value as item.label for item in f.options | filter: myProcessFilter('some value')" />
```

But when I do that, the (v, i) no longer gets automatically passed.  So I want to pass it in manually.  However, I don't know how to access the iterable from within the ng-options directive.  I tried:

```
<select ng-model="f.value" ng-options="item.value as item.label for item in f.options | filter: myProcessFilter(item)" />
```

And

```
<select ng-model="f.value" ng-options="item.value as item.label for item in f.options | filter: myProcessFilter(this)" />
```

But neither work.  I'm having trouble googling the right thing, i'm sure this is simple!  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that in the first version of your code, you're using `… | filter: myProcessFilter`, without parenthesis. What you're passing to the [`filter` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) is a function, **not what this function is returning**.

That should always be the case: the [`filter` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) **need** a function. If, for some reasons, it also need an additional variable to work, you should use an intermediate function in order to do the job:

```
<select ng-model="f.value" ng-options="… | filter: createMyProcessFilter('Some value')" />
```

```
function createMyProcessFilter(additionalValue)
{
    return function myProcessFilter(v, i) {
        // You can now use v, i AND additionalValue here!
    };
}
```